# Why does my Alert Dialog not open?

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

I have the Problem that the Dialog Box with "Take Photo", "Choose from Gallery" and Cancel isn't showing. 
Below I have added the code.

Wizard.Java:

```
public class Wizard extends Activity {

    ImageView viewImage;
    Button b;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSelectPhoto);
        viewImage=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.viewImage);
        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                selectImage();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds options to the action bar if it is       
    present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

      private void selectImage() {

        final CharSequence[] options = { "Take Photo", "Choose from   
    Gallery","Cancel" };

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Wizard.this);
        builder.setTitle("Add Photo!");
        builder.setItems(options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                if (options[item].equals("Take Photo"))
                {
                    Intent intent = new 
    Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    File f = new   

    File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "temp.jpg");
                    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, 

    Uri.fromFile(f));
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
                }
                else if (options[item].equals("Choose from Gallery"))
                {
                    Intent intent = new     


          Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 2);

                }
                else if (options[item].equals("Cancel")) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            }
        });
        builder.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == 1) {
                File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString());
                for (File temp : f.listFiles()) {
                    if (temp.getName().equals("temp.jpg")) {
                        f = temp;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                try {
                    Bitmap bitmap;
                    BitmapFactory.Options bitmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();

                    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath(),
                            bitmapOptions); 

                    viewImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                    String path = android.os.Environment
                            .getExternalStorageDirectory()
                            + File.separator
                            + "Phoenix" + File.separator + "default";
                    f.delete();
                    OutputStream outFile = null;
                    File file = new File(path, String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg");
                    try {
                        outFile = new FileOutputStream(file);
                        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, outFile);
                        outFile.flush();
                        outFile.close();
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else if (requestCode == 2) {

                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                String[] filePath = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
                Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,filePath, null, null, null);
                c.moveToFirst();
                int columnIndex = c.getColumnIndex(filePath[0]);
                String picturePath = c.getString(columnIndex);
                c.close();
                Bitmap thumbnail = (BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
                Log.w("path of image from gallery......******************.........", picturePath+"");
                viewImage.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

Wizard.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="284dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:ems="10" 
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:maxLength="10">
        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

     <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnSelectPhoto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Select Photo" />

     <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/viewImage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/camera"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Is your problem that the `AlertDialog` is not shown (as says your question's title) or that "cancel isn't showing" as yout question says?..

Comment: @shkschneider The whole AlertDialog isn't showing, nor in the Emulator nor in my Test Device :/

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom alertdialog.

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
View dialoglayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_layout, null);
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setView(dialoglayout);builder.show();
```

before you must create *dialog_layout.xml*

Answer (score 0):

are you sure that it doesn't work? Your code is correct. It could be perfectly show on Nexus 5.

Comment: I'm Sure, i tested it on the Emulator and on my Phone.

Comment: is there some valued logs when alert dialog doesn't show?

Comment: Unfortunately no, maybe I should mention that I implented this with the help of a tutorial, and i didn't use my MainActivity. @BinGoBinBin